# Rust HashMap find and remove minimum value

Tags: rust, priority-queue

I have a `HashMap<(usize,usize),Point3d>` and I want to remove the minimum element according to some metric.

```
        let closest_edge = {
            let edges = exterior.keys();
            edges.reduce(|k1:&(usize,usize),k2:&(usize,usize)|-> &(usize,usize) {
                // return minimal value
            }).unwrap()
        };

        exterior.remove(closest_edge);
```

However, I cannot remove the minimal edge because of a borrow as immutable in getting the keys from `exterior`. Specifically this is my error:

```
cannot borrow `exterior` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Is there an idiomatic way to write a queue that reshuffles?

`Queue` doesn't work because I want the minimal element, not the oldest element.

`retain` also doesn't work because I would need to know what the minimal distance is before hand, and I want to only remove one element.

`PriorityQueue` is also not quite right, since the priority may change from round to round. (Each round I want to find an edge that is closest to the point I'm looking at, so the distance function changes each time)

Comment: `closest_edge` is a `&(usize, size)`?! Then you can simply de-reference it, as it is `Copy`, and re-borrow for the `remove()`-call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your key is `Copy`, you can copy it by dereferencing so it isn't borrowing from the map.

```rust
let closest_edge = {
    let edges = exterior.keys();
    // Dereference *
    *edges.reduce(|k1:&(usize,usize),k2:&(usize,usize)|-> &(usize,usize) {
        // return minimal value
    }).unwrap()
};

// Make temporary reference &
exterior.remove(&closest_edge);
```